# Searching for a specific header and then looking up a value based on a customer ID

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16GTyLHwQ6roZ445rX0zf2mR4KLjtDVb-u3AhQi0l1QI/edit?usp=sharing

Hi,

I am trying to search for a specific column on the second sheet and return the value based off the ID number.

The problem is each time the report is run the cell reference of the report changes. For example if Contact withCustomer count is in B4 this week it might be B7 next time.

I thought it was a combination of Vlookup index and match but I can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=index(ifna(vlookup(B2:B,choosecols('export data'!1:1000,xmatch(B1,'export data'!1:1),xmatch(G1,'export data'!1:1)),2,)))
```

- the formula dynamically searches for both the `Id` and `Contact with Customer count` columns in your `export data` tab & then looks-up the respective customer_count value for each Id

[image]

Comment: This should work if you wish to hardcode the header titles direct into the formula: `=index(ifna(vlookup(B2:B,choosecols('export data'!1:1000,xmatch("Id",'export data'!1:1),xmatch("Contact with Customer count",'export data'!1:1)),2,)))`